# How can I get full URL of current page with xpath on InfoPath 2010 form?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, xpath

I want to open different forms for different SharePoint list views so I need to get current page full URL on an InfoPath 2010 form. How can I do this through XPath or XQuery?

Answer (score -1):

Probably you do not need full URL but only that part that triggers default views?

Most Infopath 2010 controls have "Insert Function..." button where you can choose various URL functions, related to your context

For example, here is an image of text box properties in context of infopath form for (in context of) a list:

[image]

Now, when you tell about Xpath or JQuery, you most probably do not understand that Infopath is codeless approach to crating forms.
Even more, in **<s>browser-enabled</s> Sharepoint List Form type** (which only make sense for your questions) Infopath forms the custom code is IMPOSSIBLE at all!!!

Take it or leave it altogether.

**Update:**
Infpath form is just XML-based from, i.e. just XML data used by, for ex., Sharepoint Server 2010 for rendering this form at runtime.

The same IP form is used, depending on context, in different web pages.

As such, determining a web page URL from inside of and by means of Infopath form, by quering its own XML data does not make sense to me. IP form does not control its use, it is just being used from outside. Page URL is external data for IP form, you should get this URL  outside of IP form and pass/return it to Infopath Form Web part, if you want to show it there.

You can't learn dynamic or run-time or external data by querying internal or static or XML data of infopath form. You can provide it by external means only and use it by external means only.

How to do it is another and different question

For example,
create web part detecting full page URL. I hope it is easily searchable in internet.

On design surface of web page in browser (Site Actions --> Edit Page), place this web part and  in your Infopath Form Web Part click small-black-down-arrow drop-down-list on the upper right corner --->  Connections --> Get Data (Filter Value) From --> Click the name of your placed web part  --> on the following popup dialog choose the field where to put caught data in "Consumer Field Name" drop-down list.

Comment: Yes, I need only a part of page URL, actually, I need site page name, like .../../MyPage.aspx
I want to learn page URL to decide to open a custom InfoPath 2010 form view. I guess this can be learn through XPath or XQuery, not JQuery.
And again yes, InfoPath is a codeless approach to create forms but you can type custom XPath codes on there.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Once again, you cannot get it from Infopath form because the same Infopath form is used in different contexts and web pages. It cannot know how it will be used

Comment: "Even more, in browser-enabled (which only make sense for your questions) Infopath forms the custom code is IMPOSSIBLE at all!!! " </p>
Sorry, why? Browser-enabled IP-forms have some restrictions, but you can use code in it

Comment: -1 for "the custom code is IMPOSSIBLE at all!!!"

Comment: 'browser-enabled' was a typo which I changed to 'Sharepoint list Form type'.